# How to print an arraylist such that it is the power of all the prime numbers with an upperbound

Tags: java, for-loop, primes

I want to get an arraylist of all the numbers that are powers of primes below or equal to the upperbound.

this is what I got:

```
public class PrimePowers {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getPrimePowers(10));
}

public static List<Integer> getPrimePowers(int upperBound) {
ArrayList<Integer> primePower = new ArrayList<>();
for (int flag = 2; flag <= upperBound; flag++){

}

    return ;
}
public static List<Integer> getPrimeNumbers(int upperBound){
    ArrayList<Integer> primeNumber = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 2; i <=upperBound; i++){
        if (!isPrime(i)) {
            if(i != 1) {
                primeNumber.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return primeNumber;

}
public static boolean isPrime(int num){
    boolean flag = false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; ++i) {
        // condition for nonPrime number
        if (num % i == 0) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}
}
```

so I have all the primenumbers, now I have to get all their powers below the upperbound.
my first question: how do I get all their powers, without getting 2 of the same in the list? or is that not an issue?
my second question: how do I program it such that I can get the power to also keep continuing going up, until the upper bound? i.e. if the upper bound is 10, with prime number 2 I should get 2^2 = 4 and 2^3 = 8.

an example:
program is called as getPrimePowers(50)
return: [4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32, 49]

sorry if this is really confusion, but I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IntStream`:

- Create an `IntStream` with values between 2 and the square root of
  the upper bound.
- Filter the stream prime numbers.
- Flat map the stream for the powers using an `IntStream` mapper, map it to the power and filter values that are lower than the upper bound.
- Finally, sort the resulting stream and collect it to a `List`.

Summaraizing in a method:

```
public static List<Integer> primePower(int upperBound) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, (int) Math.sqrt(upperBound))
            .filter(i -> isPrime(i))
            .flatMap(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(2, 
                        (int) Math.rint(Math.pow(upperBound, 1d / i)))
                    .map(j -> (int) Math.pow(i, j))
                    .filter(j -> j <= upperBound))
            .distinct().sorted()
            .boxed().toList();
}
    
private static boolean isPrime(int value) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, (int) Math.sqrt(value))
      .allMatch(i -> value % i != 0);
}
```

Test:

```
List<Integer> primePower = primePower(50);

System.out.println(primePower);
```

Output:

```
[4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32, 49]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to calculate all the primes that are smaller then the upper bound, use [isProbablePrime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime(int)), which is way faster than any implementation you will write.

Secondly, after you collected all the primes, for each one of them you can calculate all their power by:

```
prime = ...
int max_power = (int)Math.floor(Math.log(upperBound) / Math.log(prime));
for (int p = 1, val = 1; p <= max_power; p++)
    result.add(val *= prime);
```

Thirdly, you can't get any duplication (except the number 1), because each number can be factorized into primes in exactly one way, so don't worry about it.